# Put two buttons on top of an image

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put buttons on top of an image with this code:

```
return Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
                child: Stack(
                  children:[
                    Image(
                      image: NetworkImage('https://static.vix.com/es/sites/default/files/styles/4x3/public/imj/p/paisajes-espectaculares-del-mundo-1.jpg'),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.android),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      iconSize: 50,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.android),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      iconSize: 200,
                    ),
                  ]
                )
              ),
            );
```

It put the buttons, both at the top of the image, but put them together, although they have Alignment in the center on the right and in the center on the left each respectively. The result of this code looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alignment` property inside an `IconButton` is to align the icon of the button only (read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/alignment.html)). You can use `AlignmentDirectional.center` and `Positioned` instead:

```dart
FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
            child: Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://static.vix.com/es/sites/default/files/styles/4x3/public/imj/p/paisajes-espectaculares-del-mundo-1.jpg'),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.android),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      iconSize: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 0,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.android),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      iconSize: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `IconButton`s in `Positioned` or in `Align` widget and place them for your likings

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using Stack widget.
Make sure to follow official Flutter guide on Stack widget in the video down below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8